# Why is my username in the terminal not green

Tags: lxterminal

My username in the terminal usually green.

It is no longer green.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Which OS ? Is this on a Pi ?

Comment: Are you logged in locally or remotely? Did you edit the .bashrc file?

Comment: Looks like maybe you had a custom prompt before, but it's somehow been reset to default.  You might want to google "BASH Prompt Basics".  There are lots of resources out there on how to customize it to your own desires.  It won't be long before you have your green user ID back!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your ~/.bashrc file might have been modified.  On a Rasberry Pi, the default Raspbian ~/.bashrc file has the following code in it for setting the prompt color:

```
# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w \$\[\033[00m\] '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

Check to see if you have something similar, and if not, then you can try putting this code in, or maybe even set up your own custom prompt.  For a great tutorial on how to do this, check out: [How to customize your BASH Prompt](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-customize-your-bash-prompt-on-a-linux-vps).