# User and location line disappeared at new user

Tags: login, user

When you log in with the standard pi user in commandline, you see like pi@hostname and after that the location path you're in. But when I create a new user and log in into that, that line disappears... How can I get that back?

Comment: What happens if you type `bash` ... What is the output of `cat /etc/passwd/ |grep newuser` ... the last colon separated field shows the default shell for that user.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the necessary `.bashrc` code is not in the new user's home directory.  Check out my answer to a similar question here for a possible solution:

[Why is my username in the terminal not green](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/75575/why-is-my-username-in-the-terminal-not-green/75584#75584)

Good luck!